# What is the equation of the plane?

Tags: surfaces

Suppose a plane has a unit normal vector of $\left(\frac {1}{\sqrt6} , \frac {1}{\sqrt6} , \frac {2}{\sqrt6}\right)$ and is at a signed distance of $\left(\frac {13}{\sqrt6}\right)$ from the origin. What is the equation of the plane?

So given $d$ = - ($n$ $\cdot$ $p$) and my $n$ = $\left(\frac {1}{\sqrt6} , \frac {1}{\sqrt6} , \frac {2}{\sqrt6}\right)$

Can I say that my $p$, which is $(x , y , z)$ , is $(1 , 1 , 2)$?

so my d = - $\left(\frac {1}{\sqrt6} , \frac {1}{\sqrt6} , \frac {2}{\sqrt6}\right)$ . (1 , 1 , 2) = -${\sqrt6}$

so my equation of plane is  $\frac {1}{\sqrt6} , \frac {1}{\sqrt6} , \frac {2}{\sqrt6}-\sqrt6=0$.

Is this correct?

How can I work out my distance to be $\frac {13}{\sqrt6}$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Do you mean your equation is $x/\sqrt6 + y/\sqrt6 + 2z/\sqrt6 - \sqrt6 = 0$?

Comment: No, it's not correct.

Answer (score 2):

The general plane with your unit normal  $n$ has equation
$$x+y+2z=a$$
for some real $a$. To find $a$ you must have the point $(13/\sqrt6)n$
on the plane. That point is $(13/6,13/6,13/3)$.

Comment: So, what's $a$?

Comment: so am I right to say 1/√6 + 1/√6 + 2/√6 − 13/√6 = 0 is the equation of the plane?

Comment: @confusedbeginner You insist in writing a false equation of **numbers**...! That can't be a plane: you need $\;x,y,z\;$ ...

Comment: x/√6 + y/√6 + 2z/√6 − 13/√6 = 0. Sorry, I was just focusing on the finding the a in the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Since the distance between point $\;(a,b,c)\;$ to plane $\;Ax+By+Cz+D=0\;$ is given by

$$\frac{|Aa+Bb+Cc+D|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}\;,\;\;\text{your plane is given by the conditions:}$$

$$\begin{cases}&\frac1{\sqrt6}x+\frac1{\sqrt6}y+\frac2{\sqrt6}z+d=0\\{}\\
&\cfrac{|d|}{\sqrt{\frac16+\frac16+\frac46}}=\cfrac{13}{\sqrt6}\end{cases}$$

So you can write your plane's equation as

$$x+y+2z+13=0$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the plane whose unit normal is $\hat{\underline{n}}$ and which is at a signed distance $d$ from the origin is given by $$\underline{r}\cdot\hat{\underline{n}}=d$$

So the equation of this plane is $$x+y+2z=13$$